# webview- onPageFinished is not working

Tags: android, webview

I want webview to load another site when the page is done, but it won't work. Here is my code;

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
     {

         webView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
     }
}
```

Comment: Try changing webView.loadUrl to view.loadUrl

Comment: Have you given the INTERNET Permission ? Please post your AndroidManifest.xml + your error log if any.

Comment: yeah, google loads fine, its onpageload. when google finally loads, the onpageload command seems not to work and facebook wont load

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set a webViewClient and override its methods to achieve the call to onPageFinished. In the code thats been posted I don't see any Override annotations, please refer to the sample code below,

```
    private WebView myWebView;
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override  
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      super.onPageFinished(myWebView, url);
      //Do something
      myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
    }  
   });
```